# HaGadol HaGibor veHaNora

Tags: words, theology, shemoneh-esrei

In the beginning of the amida prayer, God is ascribed these three titles: HaGadol HaGibor veHaNora. (the source is from the torah)

What does each one mean and how are they different?

Comment: doesnt the gamoro in barochoth talk bout this?

Comment: I think Moshe said them before the Amida was written.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob where?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin i forgot where but maybe in the 20s? it goes something like, why do we say hajodhol hajeebor wahanoro? and it says one novi said hajodhol in this situation in navee'eem, then anotehr novi said this and the other said that, and we have to stop a person from saying more than these 3 because there is no end to the praises for HaShem therefore if he keeps on going and stops at a certain places someone will say that he only praises this amount but not fully. something along those lines. maybe not in the 20s but early 30s where it talks about when to stop a shalia7 9ibbur in the 2nd rep

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob I don't think it says what do they mean, just that we can say only those three.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin i think it explains the reason for why those 3 were chosen though. so its some type of meaning

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob Because those three are in the Chumash

Comment: @ShmuelBrin i thnk the argument was that they were in navee'eem not in 7umash and it was an argument as to why the novi used those 2 particular words if they dont fit the situation the novi was in. and same for the other 2 navee'eem.and it explains what each word means and why they dont fit the situation.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob it wasn't Chumash vs Navi. It was Chumash vs made up.

Comment: Mountains are big, blue whales are both big and strong, hurricanes are big and strong and scary. They are listed in order of ascending awe and serve as a meditative build up to kel Elyon, which then is brought back down with the rest of the blessing, culminating in this awesome king being our shield, a most immediate presence and protection. Partially rabbi Aryeh Kaplan in Jewish meditation, partially me.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin u sure?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob Just go find it and settle this discussion for good. The Gemara that Shmuel refers to is Brachot 33b.

Comment: @Justaguy very interesting. thanks. some interpret HaNora as referring to wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

Hagadol- great, created the universe and everything

Hagibor- powerful, runs the whole world and decides everything for the whole world

WeHanora- awesome, feared by the creatures of the world

Source: Siddur Ish Masliah and Kawanat Halev.

Comment: thnx. great in deeds? gibor usually means might or strength. what's the connection to deciding everything. i once read that nora refers to His

Answer (score 1):

Gadol refers to Hashem's middas hatava, as chazal say in devarim 23:4 "es gadlecha - zu middas tuvcha."  See the Maharsha on the gemara in Yuma 69b (which was referenced in comments above, it is the gemara about why the Anshei Knesses Hagedola got that name, who explains gadol along these lines in answering why they were called Hagedola if gadol was the one description that wasn't removed by the nevi'im).

Gibbor is that Hashem is kovesh es yitzro (overcomes His will, so to speak) and allows the resha'im to exist (gemara there)

Norah is that Hashem protects "one sheep among 70 wolves" and sustains our existence in Galus (gemara there)

The iyun tefillah says gadol refers to brias haolam, gibbor is yetzias Mitzrayim, and Norah is krias yam suf.